# light on rendering obj file in python

Tags: python, opengl, pywavefront

I  have  an obj file,  I want to render it with light however I have zero knowledge about graphics

please see the output

[image]

and the following is the obj file  [ex.obj](https://filebin.net/q2fl2uqitqby9568/ex.obj?t=7yvynw1l)

this the code I found in the net

what I want is light (diffuse light I think) , the texture of the shape not appearing it looks like mask

```
import ctypes
import sys

sys.path.append('..')
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

from pywavefront import visualization
import pywavefront
import pywavefront.material

rotation = 0
#meshes = pywavefront.Wavefront('ex.obj')

meshes = pywavefront.Wavefront('ex.obj')


print '==================='
window = pyglet.window.Window()
lightfv = ctypes.c_float * 4

@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(60., float(width)/height, 0.01, 100.)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    return True

global rotatex, rotatey, zoom, outName
rotatex = 0
rotatey = 0
zoom=0
outName = "test.png"

@window.event
def on_draw():
    global rotatex, rotatey, outName
    lightfv = ctypes.c_float * 4
    window.clear()
    glLoadIdentity()
    #glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightfv(-40.0, 200.0, 100.0, 0.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightfv(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightfv(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

    glTranslated(0, -1, -6)
    glRotatef(-66.5, 0, 0, 1)
    glRotatef(rotation, 1, 0, 0)
    glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1)
    glRotatef(0, 0, 1, 0)

    visualization.draw(meshes)

    pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(outName)

    #exit()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Make sure you export you meshes with normal data. If you are using Blender, you will need to select "Write Normals" in the export settings panel.

Comment: `glTranslated` operates with doubles, but you're using floats elsewhere. You should replace it with `glTranslatef`, or, better, use modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

Your model file has no normals information included, it is needed to approximate the surface lighting.

Judging by the model look, it seems it wasn't modeled but 3d-scanned, and the surface was reconstructed from the volumetric dataset with marching cubes algorithm, so exporting the "real" normals isn't an option.

Now you can either find the wavefront object importer that can recalculate the normals for you (pywavefront doesn't), or import it into 3D modeling app (like Blender), mark the faces as smooth or sharp, and re-export it with normals included. The result will be less than perfect, because the original surface is lost, and normals will be built for this blocky voxel-ish mesh you have on hands.

The model file will become something like this: [ex_normals.obj](https://filebin.net/moisht7kc8x8ea4r/ex_normals.obj?t=7utvhwjd)

And the render will look like this:
[image: normals recalculated]

Comment: Given link is broken.